# Suppose that the characteristic polynomial for S is irreducible. Then show that S and T are equivalent iff...

Tags: linear-algebra

The question:

> Let $V$ denote a finite dimensional vector space over a field $F$ and let $S,T:V \to V$ be linear transformations. Suppose that the characteristic polynomial for $S$ is irreducible. Then show that $S$ and $T$ are equivalent iff  $S$ and $T$ have the same characteristic polynomial [$\det(S-tI) = \det(T-tI)$].

I proved that if $S$ and $T$ are equivalent, then the characteristic polynomials of $S$ and $T$ are equal to each other. It seemed pretty straight forward since $S$ and $T$ being equivalent entails that we have to different bases (say $v_1$ and $v_2$) s.t the coordinate matrix of S relative to $v_1$ is equal to the coordinate matrix of T relative to $v_2$. All being said, this implies that they have equal determinants and thus equal characteristic polynomials.

What I'm asking for help on is the converse. I've been trying to use the fact that the characteristic polynomial of $S$ is irreducible $\implies$ the characteristic polynomial of $T$ is irreducible, but I've got no idea where to go from there. :( If anyone can help, I'd be much obliged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case where $S,T$ have equal *irreducible* characteristic polynomials is relatively easy; it should be noted though that one could get the same conclusion (similarity), but with a different proof, under the weaker hypothesis of a equal square-free characteristic polynomials, or even when $S,T$ just have equal characteristic polynomials that are also their minimal polynomials. Since the minimal polynomial divides the characteristic polynomial (by the Cayley-Hamilton theorem) it is clear that here $S,T$ have their minimal polynomials equal to their common characteristic polynomial.

Irreducibility of the characteristic polynomial has a stronger consequence though: there are no non-trivial $S$-stable (or $T$-stable) subspaces (the only such spaces are the zero subspace and the whole space). Because the characteristic polynomial of the restriction of $S$ to any $S$-stable subspace$~W$ divides the full characteristic polynomial of$~S$ (on$~V$), but that is only possible here if it has degree $0$ or $n=\dim V$.

This means that if one takes any nonzero vector $v$, then the family $v,Sv,S^2v,\ldots,S^{n-1}v$ is linearly independent, and therefore form a basis of$~V$: if any $S^kv$ would be linearly dependent on the preceding vectors, then those vectors would span an $S$-stable subspace, which is impossible. But $S^nv$ can of course be expressed in this basis $S^nv=c_0v+c_1Sv+\cdots+c_{n-1}S^{n-1}v$, and then $X^n-c_{n-1}X^{n-1}-\cdots-c_1X-c_0$ is the minimal (and characteristic) polynomial of $S$. But the same is true for $T$: the vectors $v,Tv,T^2v,\ldots,T^{n-1}v$ form a basis, and one has for the *same* collection of coefficients that $T^nv=c_0v+c_1Tv+\cdots+c_{n-1}T^{n-1}v$. But that means that $S$ has the same (companion) matrix with respect to the basis $v,Sv,S^2v,\ldots,S^{n-1}v$ as $T$ has with respect to the basis $v,Tv,T^2v,\ldots,T^{n-1}v$: the matrices are therefore similar.